# Prevent or handle click event on child and parent tags in same section

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have developed the **onclick** functionality which performs specific operation regardless of clicks of tags, it seems like when I click on child tag or child click event fires its relevant parent click event automatically fired.

Need to prevent the event or handle event related to a specific tag is clicked.

What I want is when parent tag is clicked then only parent **onclick** function should fire, in case of child tag is clicked then only a child's **onclick** event should be fired.

The same functionality developed using the react app(**reactjs**) but the result is the same, can not able to handle the **onclick** event separately.

```html
<div onClick="console.log('div tag click event fired')">
  <h1 onClick="console.log('h1 tag click event fired')">This is a Heading</h1>
  <p onClick="console.log('p tag click event fired')">This is a paragraph.</p>
<div>
```

Comment: This is what event bubbling is. You need event.stopPropagation(). Here is more info : https://medium.com/@vsvaibhav2016/event-bubbling-and-event-capturing-in-javascript-6ff38bec30e

Comment: @ShubhamVerma I have tried this but seems like its not worked in react application, can you provide more information or sample live example with the reactjs.

Comment: here is the sample [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/event-stop-propogation-yp511)

Comment: @uday great, this is what i want. Thank you so much for providing such an example. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using [Event stop propagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) keeps the event from bubbling any further up into the DOM. here is [sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/event-stop-propogation-yp511)

Answer (score 1):

use event.stopPropogation() to prevent event from bubbling to parent.

```
<div onClick="console.log('div tag click event fired')">
        <h1  onClick="console.log('h1 clicked');event.stopPropagation();">This is a Heading</h1>
        <p onClick="console.log('p tag click event fired'); event.stopPropagation();">This is a paragraph.</p>
    <div>
```

with react it's slightly different from vanilla js, you can check it here:https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html